# PHP slightly increment value based on number of decimals

Tags: php, decimal, increment

I am trying to slightly increment a value based on the number of decimals it has.

For example if the value is 1.2 I would increase it by 0.1, 12.345 by 0.001, 12.345678 by 0.000001, etc.

I currently have a long implementation using a chain of if, else if. I know this is not the most efficient way and a loop can be used, but I was unsure of how to structure the loop. I tried using the PHP substr_replace function, but I could not get it to work for this.

Is there another way I can structure a loop to reduce my lines of code and be more efficient?

Here is my php code so far:

```
$valueOne = 12.345678;

// get amount of decimals
$decimal = strlen(strrchr($valueOne, '.')) -1;

/*
this also works for finding how many decimals
$test = floatval($valueOne);
for ( $decimal_count = 0; $test != round($test, $decimal_count); $decimal_count++ );
echo $decimal_count;
*/

// see value before change
echo $valueOne;
if ($decimal == "1") {
    $valueOne = $valueOne + 0.1;
}
else if ($decimal == "2") {
    $valueOne = $valueOne + 0.01;
}
else if ($decimal == "3") {
    $valueOne = $valueOne + 0.001;
}
// etc ...
// see value after change
echo $valueOne;

/*
i tried messing around with using a loop, but did not have much luck
$start = 0.1;
$count = 0;
$position = 2;
while ($count != $decimal) {
    echo substr_replace($start, 0, $position, 0) . "<br />\n";
    $count++;
    //$position++;
}

*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the number of digits after the decimal. Then create a number with a decimal point, one less `0`, followed by `1`, to get the amount to add.

```
$valueOne = 12.345678;

// get amount of decimals
$decimal = strlen(strrchr($valueOne, '.')) -1;

// see value before change
echo $valueOne . "<br>\n";

// Get amount to add
$increment = '.' . str_repeat('0', $decimal-1) . '1';

$valueOne += $increment;

echo $valueOne;
```

Comment: @Barmer Thanks for your help! How would I adjust the code if there was a 0 at the end of the decimal, for example if the number is 12.3450, the code ignores the 0 and outputs 12.346. How I can get it to output 12.3451?

Comment: You have to write the number as a string: `"12.3450"`. Otherwise the PHP parser ignores trailing zeroes, there's no way to tell that it was originally written that way.

Answer (score 1):

Get the number of decimals

Multiply by the appropriate factor so the number is now an integer

Increment by 1

Divide by the same factor to get back to the original number (properly incremented)

```
function increment($number){
  // get amount of decimals
  $decimal = strlen(strrchr($valueOne, '.')) -1;

  $factor = pow(10,$decimal);

  $incremented = (($factor * $number) + 1) / $factor;

  return $incremented;
}
```

Comment: $valueOne is not defined,maybe you have $number in mind